# How to decode RTP/MP4A-LATM audio payload

Tags: h.264, rtp, mp4a

I am working on an implementation of RTSP in J2ME to connect to Wowza. I have the RTSP part working, and the extraction of RTP packets. I am able to decode and display the h264 video stream.

I am having problems understanding how to create an appropriate audio stream to pass to a J2ME Player object.

As part of the RTSP Setup exchange I get the following information from SDP

`m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 MP4A-LATM/24000/1
a=fmtp:96 profile-level-id=15;object=2;cpresent=0;config=400026103FC0
a=control:trackID=1`

From this I know that I can expect RTP packets, containing MP4A-LATM format audio, and (most importantly) the mux config data is not present in line with the stream. The mux config data is 400026103FC0

I just don't know how to interpret the config string, and how I might configure a J2ME Player.